# Shortest way to get String from part of Bytes

Tags: vb.net

I have read bytes from file and I have to get a String from known location.

```
Dim b() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("MYFILE.BIN")
Dim myYear As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
```

That gives whole file in `myYear` String so I can extract a year from there.
Is there some handy and shortest way to get bytes from 50 to 54 and convert only that part to string?

Comment: GetString has an overload that accepts start and length,  i.e. .ASCII.GetString(b, 50, 4)

Comment: dbassnet, I don't know how I can't find this but I searched exactly for that, thank you.

Comment: I keep a bookmark for MSDN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding.GetString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like the following. Its not shorter but you don't need to read the complete file into memory.

```
Using stream = File.OpenRead("c:\MYFILE.BIN")
    stream.Seek(50, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim b = New Byte(4) {}
    stream.Read(b, 0, 5)
    Dim str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
End Using
```

Comment: There are cases when showed code is for sure more suitable from mine. Thanks.